# laravel eloquent count with a groupby

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

If I'd have the following table structure

```
ID      name   type    
1       John   Admin   
2       Johan  Admin
3       Sam    User
4       Rick   User
```

How would I use Laravels Eloquent with a groupBy query, but still grab each record, and also sum up per type how many records each type has?

Example result would be as follow

```
[
    'type' => 'Admin',
    'records' => 2
    'data' => [
        0 => [
            'name' => 'John'
        ],
        1 => [
            'name' => 'Johan'
        ]
    ]
], 
[
    'type' => 'User',
    'records' => 2
    'data' => [
        0 => [
            'name' => 'Sam'
        ],
        1 => [
            'name' => 'Rick'
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: where is your query code?

Comment: what you've tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are querying all the users you should be doing the grouping after the query instead of grouping in query like:

```
$users = User::all()->groupBy('type');
```

Then you can do:

```
foreach ($allUsers as $type => $users) {
    $type; // 'Admin'
    $users->count(); // Record Count
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user->name; // 
    }
}
```

If you want the data EXACTLY like your example then it would be:

```
User::all()
    ->groupBy('type')
    ->map(function($users, $type) {
        return [
            'type'    => $type,
            'records' => $users->count(),
            'data'    => $users->pluck('name')
        ];
    })
    ->values();
```

Comment: This returns exactly what I would want. This also allows me to use this query when the types are dynamic and still group them properly together thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve this is to have a table with types related through `hasMany()` to your data.

Then you can use standard Eloquent tools without restructuring the data manually:

```
$data = Type::with('users')->withCount('users')->get();
```

Comment: How to get withCount and grouping it with user id? can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65953937/eloquent-count-nested-relationships/65954965

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use `DB::select('select * from xxx group by yyy')` to execute the query.

Comment: This would be too heavy of an sql statement to write down if you have a decently sized database.