# Eloquent Count nested relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

```
| Data     | DataChildren   | Category
----------------------------------
|  id      | id             | id
|  name    | data_id        | name
|          | category_id    |
|          | name           |
```

Data Model:

```
public function data_children() {
   return $this->hasMany(DataChildren::class, 'data_id', 'id');
}
```

DataChildren Model:

```
public function category() {
     return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

I want to get count of `Category` based on `Data` id through `DataChildren`.
I just want to take the Category records from Data so the result should be like this

```
name from category | Count of category for Data
-------------------------------------------------
Unpublished        |   1
Published          |   3
```

I've tried using this but return `null`

```
Data::withCount(['category'=> function($query){return $query->groupBy('category_id');}])->find(1);
```

Comment: It looks like you need a many to many relation ? do you have any other attributes in `DataChildren` except the foreign keys

Comment: No, it should not many to many relation it's one to many. Yes, i have another attributes @MKhalidJunaid

Comment: With your second approach what is not working are you getting invalid count ?

Comment: I got an error `Call to a member function getRelationExistenceCountQuery() on null` @MKhalidJunaid

Comment: Ok can you add details of your category model how it is related with data children

Comment: I tried using belongsToMany like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65954965/6883282 but still get the same error

Comment: I'm really sorry i missing the `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to used [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) relationship

in Category Model:

```
 public function datas()
 {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Data::class, 'data_childerens', 'category_id', 'data_id');
 }
```

Then run this Query [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) :

```
Category::withCount('datas')->get();
```

Set Data Model:

```
public function categories()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'data_childerens', 'data_id', 'data_id');
}
```

Then run this Query With and [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) :

```
Data::with('categories')->withCount('datas')->get();
```

Comment: I got an error `Call to a member function getRelationExistenceCountQuery() on null`

Comment: I'm really sorry i missing the `return`

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! :D. I don't see many to many pattern because the real model  have so many attributes xD. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: I want to get name and count for `Data`. How is it? `withCount` just to get the number but i need to get `name` too

Comment: `Data::withCount(['category'=> function($query){return $query->groupBy('category_id');}])->find(1);` . I tried this but return `null`

Comment: @RayCoder now you will get data name